# HttpWebRequest throws System.Net.WebException Section=ResponseStatusLine

Tags: c#, http, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I wrote a simple httpserver which i plan to interact with with HttpRequest/Response. The server gets the request and the parsing is fine but when i write back i get exception

```
System.Net.WebException: Der Server hat eine Protokollverletzung ausgeführt. Section=ResponseStatusLine
   bei System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

my servercode which writes back

```
TcpClient client = ...;
_stream = _client.GetStream();


// make sure "\r\n" is used as line ending, because it may be different on different OS
_output = new StreamWriter(_stream, Encoding.UTF8) { NewLine = "\r\n" };

length = 0;
code = 200;
message = "OK";
_output.WriteLine("HTTP/1.1 " + code + " " + message);
_output.WriteLine("Server: My Server");
_output.WriteLine("ContentLength: " + length);
_output.WriteLine("Connection: " + (_keepAlive ? "Keep-Alive" : "Close"));
_output.WriteLine();
_output.Flush();
```

client code

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://127.0.0.1:8080/foo");
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;

using (var res = request.GetResponse())   // throws here
{
}
```

any idea?

Update: as Jon mentioned first bug removed but still not working

alternate client code

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
{
    client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 8080));
    using (var stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine("GET /foo HTTP/1.1");
        writer.WriteLine("HOST:127.0.0.1");
        writer.WriteLine("Connection:Close");
        writer.WriteLine();
        writer.Flush();

        var response = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
        foreach (var c in response)
        {
            if (char.IsControl(c))
                Console.Write("'{0}'" , (int)c);
            else
                Console.Write(c);
        }
    }
}
```

returns

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK'13''10'Server: My custom Server'13''10'ContentLength: 0'13''10'Connection: Close'13''10''13''10'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is very suspect to start with:

```
_output = new StreamWriter(_stream, Encoding.UTF8) { NewLine = "\n\r" };
```

I think you meant `\r\n` rather than `\n\r`.

Comment: you are right, i missed that. But its still giving me the exception

Comment: @Firo: Can you provide a short but *complete* program for both server and client? And is there any reason you're not using `HttpListener`, out of interest?

Comment: 1) i planed to run it on hosted linux and was afraid that HttpListener is not well supported or needs some extra security stuff. 2) the basic example how to create your own http server looked very simple (2 pages code) and had `ProcessGETRequest(...)` with available properties instead of HttpListenerRequest with lots of properties which are only applicable in some special situations.

Comment: its working with httplistener returning `HTTP/1.1 200 OK'13''10'Content-Length: 0'13''10'Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0'13''10'Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2012 12:22:04 GMT'13''10'Connection: close'13''10''13''10'` still not sure why my own server leads to bad protocoll in httprequest